# How to continuesly create sprites Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Is there any other way other than creating new sprites as sprite1,sprite2,....?I mean do i have to save a counter of the number 1,2 ...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use arrays (NSMutableArray in your case). Here's the link how to use:
http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSMutableArray

Comment: Though I don't exactly understand, yes you would want to use Arrays.

Comment: @all: There is no way naming n sprites as sprite1, sprite2 and so on. You should use array instead